# how i can create top/button and left/right scrollbar moving button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any way to make a scrollbar move using a button in JavaScript/jQuery? I have taken the screenshot from google Sheets; they have that option, but I don't how I can do the same.

[image]

Same image, but close up:

[image]

Comment: Yes it is, but please show us what you have tried. Remember that Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: There will be many ways to accomplish this. To be able to help, we will need a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are probably doing something like this:

First, you'll need to hide the default scrollbars, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll).

Next, you'll need to implement your own scrollbars, for example something like [this project on GitHub](https://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/).

Finally, when implementing your scrollbars, create buttons, (perhaps using a `<button>` tag). In the button click handler, change `.scrollTop` or `.scrollLeft` to scroll the element incrementally.

For example:

```js
document.getElementById( "my-scroll-left-button" ).onclick = () => {

    document.getElementById( "my-scroll-container" ).scrollLeft += 30;

}

document.getElementById( "my-scroll-right-button" ).onclick = () => {

    document.getElementById( "my-scroll-container" ).scrollLeft -= 30;

}

document.getElementById( "my-scroll-up-button" ).onclick = () => {

    document.getElementById( "my-scroll-container" ).scrollTop -= 30;

}

document.getElementById( "my-scroll-down-button" ).onclick = () => {

    document.getElementById( "my-scroll-container" ).scrollTop += 30;

}
```

Be warned: If you are using CSS scroll-snapping, manually changing `.scrollTop` and `.scrollLeft` might cause issues in some browsers. (I wouldn't worry about it though, since scroll-snapping is not usually a critical feature.)

Comment: this is working perfectly but bottom option is not working. kindly check below code and let me know the answer.

document.getElementById( "my-scroll-top-button" ).onclick = () => {

              document.getElementById( "content-container" ).scrollTop += 30;

              }

              document.getElementById( "my-scroll-buttom-button" ).onclick = () => {

              document.getElementById( "content-container" ).scrollBottom -= 30;

              }

Comment: Edited to include `.scrollTop` usage. There is no `.scrollBottom`, but you were very close.